# How to connect Jmeter to Vertica DB

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, vertica

I have a question about checking vertica DB with Jmeter.
I would like to create assertions on vertica DB with Jmeter.
I added JDBC connection Configuration.

Can someone please advise about what to enter in Database URL beside the host IP and the port? what is the correct syntax? and what is the jar that I need to add?

regards

P.S after your help still I can not connect get the following error Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.vertica.jdbc.Driver'

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database URL:

```
jdbc:vertica://VerticaHost:portNumber/databaseName?user=username&password=password
```

You need to know your VerticaHost and portNumber your Vertica DB installed and user and password that are available

Driver Class:

```
com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
```

For Vertica 8.1 JDBC Jar you can download [here](https://my.vertica.com/client_drivers/8.1.x/8.1.1-0/vertica-jdbc-8.1.1-0.jar), full list [here](https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/).

Put vertica-jdbc-8.1.1-0.jar in lib folder of [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html):

> To use this driver, its containing .jar file (ex.
> mysql-connector-java-X.X.X-bin.jar) must be copied to the JMeter ./lib
> directory (see JMeter's Classpath for more details).

See more in [vertica docs](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientJDBC/CreatingAndConfiguringAConnection.htm).

Comment: After I tried it I get this message   cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.vertica.jdbc.Driver' can someone please advise?

Comment: vertica-jdbc-8.1.1-0.jar should be in lib folder of JMeter

Comment: I use vertica 7.2.3  I put it in  "C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\lib\ext"  the file vertica-jdbc-7.2.3-0.jar and still not working. moreover I know that I should put the DB name, but were I sjould place the scema?

Comment: folder should be **lib** not **lib/ext** . schema and DB name you should ask your DBA about how it was created